# Get data of excel file - JSF

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file: test_excel.xls

I want to read content inside.

What I do:

1) Upload file from client

2) Parse to Base64 String (using javascript)

3) From Base64 Convert to Byte

4) Upload Byte String to server

5) I stuck in here, I don't know how to get the data, I have tried many way (Apache POI, convert to FileInputStream..)

Do anybody have ideas on this problem ?

Comment: Why are you using the client to do the base 64 decoding?  The server can do that.  The client doesn't have to be involved AFAICS.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the file, get byte[] out of it like this:

```
public static byte[] getByteStream(File file) {
    byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            //System.out.print((char) b[i]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

And use it with Apache POI or any other 'excel' framework to read its values.

P.S. you might want to clean the code, I just grabbed the first thing I remembered and from what I can see it could use some cleaning *smile*